# Why does my paragraph textContent disappear after flashing its value momentarily?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and HTML and trying to learn from scratch on my own.

In my code below, the word "Hi!" flashes for a split second right below the "Click Me!" button, then disappears altogether. Why does this keep happening?

Note: I read some other posts about submit vs button type and forms getting refreshed. I'm not even using a form tag here, and I've explicitly mentioned that *type = "button"* in my HTML file too.

```js
document.querySelector("#text").textContent = document.querySelector("#B1").addEventListener("click", showDate);

function showDate(event) {
let week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ];
let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
let date = new Date();
let day = week[date.getDay()];
let month = months[date.getMonth()];
let year = date.getFullYear();
let dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
return(`Today is ${day}, ${dayOfMonth} ${month}, ${year}.`);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="B1" type="button" >Click Me!</button>
    <p id="text">Hi!</p>
    <script src="Scripts/test2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Grateful for any solutions to this!

Comment: Take a look how event listeners work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the result of the method which will invoked in the addEventListener because it is a callback function and callback functions doesn't return anything.

> The main difference with callback-based APIs is it does not return a
> value, it just executes the callback with the result. [..]

To fix this you can remove the part before the *=*

```
document.querySelector("#B1").addEventListener("click", showDate);
```

And do the textContent assignment inside your *showDate()* function and remove the return.

```js
document.querySelector("#B1").addEventListener("click", showDate);

function showDate(event) {
let week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ];
let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
let date = new Date();
let day = week[date.getDay()];
let month = months[date.getMonth()];
let year = date.getFullYear();
let dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
document.querySelector('#text').textContent = `Today is ${day}, ${dayOfMonth} ${month}, ${year}.`;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="B1" type="button" >Click Me!</button>
    <p id="text">Hi!</p>
    <script src="Scripts/test2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can read more

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- [How to return value from addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501696/how-to-return-value-from-addeventlistener)
- [JS: Return value from EventListener function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340344/js-return-value-from-eventlistener-function)
- [https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee#:~:text=The%20main%20difference%20with%20callback,returned%20Promise%20object%20and%20calls%20](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20with%20callback,returned%20Promise%20object%20and%20calls%20).

Comment: Thank you! it works exactly as you said. I never knew that showDate function's return value cannot be accessed when used in the addEventListener function for B1.